# Finding the area under one arch of cycloid

Tags: calculus, parametrization

The question asks to find the area under one arch of the cycloid:

$$x=a(t-\sin t), y=a(1-\cos t)$$

The solution says that $A=\int_{0}^{2\pi}ydx$

I'm just confused about how they were able to get this integral. Can someone please explain how to set up this integral? Why is it not $\int y dy$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same as your standard area integral. The integral $\int_a^b f(x) dx$ represents area above the $x$-axis and below the curve $y=f(x)$, so we can replace the $f(x)$ in the integrand with a $y$.

You can also see that this should indeed be a $dx$ integral because the limits of integration are the $x$-values $0$ and $2\pi$. The cycloid never gets near the height $y=2\pi$.

That said, how do we interpret the expression $\int y dx$ in this context? We can replace the "$y$" with our expression for $y$: $a(1-\cos t)$. The "$dx$" can be replaced with $\frac{dx}{dt}dt$, taking the derivative of the $x(t)$ expression and then calculating at $dt$ integral, which also runs from $0$ to $2\pi$.

Answer (score -1):

$$
\begin{aligned}
A &=\int_{0}^{2 a\pi} y d x \\
&=\int_{0}^{2 \pi} a(1-\cos t) a(1-\cos t) d t \\
&=a^{2} \int_{0}^{2 \pi}(1-\cos t)^{2} d t \\
&=a^{2} \int_{0}^{2 \pi}\left(1-2 \cos t+\cos ^{2} t\right) d t \\
&=a^{2}\left([t-2 \sin t]_{0}^{2 \pi}+ \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \frac{1+\cos 2 t}{2} d t\right) \\
&=a^{2}\left(2 \pi+\frac{1}{2}\left[t+\frac{\sin 2 t}{2}\right]_{0}^{2 \pi}\right)\\&=a^{2}(2 \pi+\pi) \\
&=3 \pi a^{2}
\end{aligned}
$$